# WebPage Design Browser Compatibility issues

Tags: css, mobile, cross-browser, mobile-website, responsiveness

I have created a design of a website for one of my client. The issue is that it is **rendering fine on edge, chrome and fiefox** but is **not rendering properly on SAFARI MAC.** I have windows and can't test on Safari, **Can someone tell me please how I can test the design compatibility on Safari browser from my Windows??**

> Secondly, The design is being displayed perfect in all screens when **I test its responsiveness from LocalHost or in DEV mode for different devices from Browser Dev Tools devices Tab**. However, when I create its build or send it in production env and **open the url on Mobile, the design shows responsiveness issues on screens which are not in Dev mode.** ***So can someone please help me in sharing a solution by which i could test my localhost in such a way that i don't have to create builds again and again and open it in mobile.*** Bcz in dev tools, it works fine in terms of responsiveness.

Comment: Without seeing yur code it's pretty difficult to see how we can help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Having said that, have you checked your use of CSS properties against caniuse.com to see if there is something that Safari has not implemented?